# Enviroment variabiles in APK from Ionic Stencil PWA starter

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

My project it's a Stencil+Ionic PWA starter and I'm using file .env to use my enviroment variables.
On browser it's okay, but If I use Appflow and I create an APK, I have the error "process is note defined"

How can I use the enviroment variabiles to work properly on native builds?
I'm not using Angular and I've found only Angular solutions.
I don't have Growth plan so I can't use enviroment in Appflow.

Comment: The newest StencilJS has a new `env` option in `stencil.config.ts`, maybe you can use that instead.

Comment: Thank you. Btw I don't find any info about this new option inside the documentation https://stenciljs.com/docs/config
Where can I find some info?

Comment: I'll write an answer because this doesn't really fit into a comment. Not entirely sure it'll solve your problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.3.0, Stencil has an `env` option in `stencil.config.ts`. It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/commit/ab6dff1a55bd746335f3f3cbc33af9a94788c10a), which is the only documentation that's currently available for it.

Basically you do something like

```js
// stencil.config.ts

export const config: Config = {
  // ...
  env: {
    FOO: 'bar'
  }
}
```

and then in your modules you can import `Env` from Stencil:

```js
import { Component, Env } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({ tag: 'my-component' })
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return <p>{Env.foo}</p>
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'll update my stencil version, try this and let you know.

Comment: It works on browser and apk, amazing! thank you so so much.